# Determining the probability distribution of a variable from the moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given that the MGF of $X$ is $M(t)= \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{e^t}{6} + \dfrac{e^{4t}}{5} + \dfrac{3e^{5t}}{10}$ 
Find the probability distribution of $X$.

I am assuming $X$ is discrete because I got $37/15$ for the expected value of $X$ (does that mean $X$ is discrete since $E(X)$ is not a whole number??)

So if $X$ is discrete then I know $$M(t)=E(e^{Xt})= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{xt}f(x)dx.$$ So how could I solve this for $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $E(X)$ is or is not a whole number has absolutely nothing to do with whether the distribution of $X$ is discrete.

Let $X$ take on  values $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$,

Then the moment generating function of $X$, that is, $E(e^{Xt})$ is equal to 
$$p_1e^{a_1 t}+p_2 e^{a_2 t} +\cdots p_ne^{a_n t}.$$ 
Compare the above expression with the one you were given. Note that if $a_1=0$ then $p_1e^{a_1 t}=p_1$.